# Automake: Remove configure script checks with make dist

Tags: automake

I'm wondering if there is a way to remove dependency checks from a `configure` script when `make dist` is run. The purpose is that the version of the package in the repository uses `emacs` to execute lisp files and generate `.c` files, whereas those generated source files are included in the tarball when `make dist` is run. Automake supports including built files in the output tarball simply by setting `EXTRA_DIST` in the Makefile. I would like to be able to check for `emacs` only when someone tries to compile from the repository, but not when someone compiles from the tarball.

More concretely, in `configure.ac` I have:

```
 AM_PATH_LISPDIR
 AS_IF([test "$EMACS" = no], [AC_MSG_ERROR([cannot find emacs])])
```

but I would like that check not to occur after `make dist` is run. Any way to do this? If not, how is this case normally handled?

Answer (score 1):

The best method I've come up with is to check for the presence of the `Bootstrap` file. `Bootstrap` is removed from the tarball after `make dist` is run.

```
AC_CHECK_FILE([Bootstrap])
if test "$ac_cv_file_Bootstrap" == yes ; then
    <check for emacs>
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd normally set a conditional if I find the tool in `configure.ac`:

```
AM_PATH_LISPDIR
AM_CONDITIONAL([HAVE_EMACS_IN_REPOSITORY], [test "x$EMACS" != xno -a -d ".git"])
AS_IF([test "$EMACS" = no -a -d ".git"], [AC_MSG_ERROR([cannot find emacs])])
```

Then in `Makefile.am`

```
if HAVE_EMACS_IN_REPOSITORY

Execute lisp files...

Generate .c files...

endif
```

Usually `configure` ends up in the same location as `.git`.  If not, the path can be adjusted.

Comment: This isn't quite what I want. If the source is from the repository then I want to unconditionally execute the lisp files, and fail with an error if emacs isn't found.

Comment: Where is `$IN_REPOSITORY` set? This variable is really all I need. With it I can wrap `AM_PATH_LISPDIR` so that it is only checked in the repository.

Comment: @Brad, you never specified exactly what kind of kind of repository you are dealing with concretely, so I can't answer that question. Is it git, subversion, Mercurial, CVS, RCS, VSS?

Comment: It happens to be a git repository.

Comment: I usually include the bootstrap script in the tarball.  It's just easier for me to consider it a [corresponding source](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html) even if it just invokes `autoreconf`.